# How to disable parser cache for when using extension in 1.33

Tags: mediawiki

I wrote an extension for one wiki page to get content from outside URL, I just put  in that article, it will hook to my extension to call Changelog.php to execute `Changelog::getLog()`

`getLog` method using curl connects to outside the URL to get JSON content and re-format it to HTML string and return that string, they work perfectly in 1.27, but after I upgrade to 1.33, it still get the content I want, but it cached the result, when outside URL changes content it won't go with it, I need to edit and save the article to get the newest content, I try to add `$parser->getOutput()->updateCacheExpiry(0);` and `$parser->disableCache();` in getLog method but nothing changed.

Comment: That seems correct. Maybe you have enabled some unrelated cache layer, such as HTML file cache?

Comment: Excuse me @Tgr could you teach me how to check?

Comment: For one thing check the source code of the HTML page. There should be a comment starting with `NewPP limit report` which includes cache expiry, so you can see whether setting that worked. For another check the caching headers it sends and make sure the caching is not happening in your browser. Also check the value of [`$wgUseFileCache`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUseFileCache) (the easiest way is via [`shell.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Shell.php)).